Why is ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE not working with PostgreSQL column aliasing?
I'm trying to perform an INSERT operation with an ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE clause in PostgreSQL. My table contains column names with aliases (e.g., "ITEM_CODE(material_code)"), and I want to update the corresponding fields when a conflict occurs on "ITEM_CODE(material_code)". Here's the SQL query I'm using:
INSERT INTO api_itemmaster (
    "ITEM_CODE(material_code)",
    "ITEM_NAME(material_name)",
    "ITEM_GROUP_CODE",
    "UNIT(base_unit)",
    "PACK(pack_size)",
    "ITEM_CLASS_CODE(material_type)",
    "DIVISION_CODE(division)",
    "SEGMENT_CODE",
    "CAT_CODE",
    "ACTIVE",
    "FORMT",
    created_on,
    updated_on,
    active_state
) VALUES (
    '5000',
    'OSKAR',
    '225',
    'STR',
    '15',
    'ZF',
    '8000',
    '30000',
    '004',
    '1',
    '20',
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    false
) ON CONFLICT ("ITEM_CODE(material_code)") 
DO UPDATE SET
    "ITEM_NAME(material_name)" = EXCLUDED."ITEM_NAME(material_name)",
    "ITEM_GROUP_CODE" = EXCLUDED."ITEM_GROUP_CODE",
    "UNIT(base_unit)" = EXCLUDED."UNIT(base_unit)",
    "PACK(pack_size)" = EXCLUDED."PACK(pack_size)",
    "ITEM_CLASS_CODE(material_type)" = EXCLUDED."ITEM_CLASS_CODE(material_type)",
    "DIVISION_CODE(division)" = EXCLUDED."DIVISION_CODE(division)",
    "SEGMENT_CODE" = EXCLUDED."SEGMENT_CODE",
    "CAT_CODE" = EXCLUDED."CAT_CODE",
    "ACTIVE" = EXCLUDED."ACTIVE",
    "FORMT" = EXCLUDED."FORMT",
    updated_on = EXCLUDED.updated_on;

However, the ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE clause doesn't seem to work, and no updates are applied to the existing row.
Ensured that the table and column names are correct.
Verified that the ITEM_CODE(material_code) constraint is unique in the table.
Confirmed that the syntax aligns with PostgreSQL's ON CONFLICT documentation.

Your syntax seems OK.  Are you getting an error message?  To help you further we need an MRE.  Your MRE should provide DDL statements to create table and constraints and insert statements to add sample data

My table contains column names with aliases - a table-column-name isn't an alias by definition. You only have an alias if you rename a column when selecting from a table/view/etc. Regarding your question - if the ON CONFLICT isn't being run then you must be getting "duplicate unique value" errors.

How do you know that you are getting conflicts in the first place?

Welcome to the SO community. The community will help you with issues, but there are some expectation of you. Please spend a few minuets to Take the Tour and review [ask]. Then update your question to include table definition(s) (DDL), sample data, and expected results. All as formatted text or even better a fiddle, but - no images.
